# Given a specific tensor on $V^{\otimes d}$, which $GL(V)$ orbit does the tensor belong to?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, tensor

Suppose we have a vector space $V$ over a field $K$, with basis vectors $\hat{\bf{e}}_k$, and suppose we define a tensor

$$
\Lambda = \lambda_{i_1, ..., i_d} (\hat{\bf{e}}_{i_1} \otimes ... \otimes \ \hat{\bf{e}}_{i_d})
$$

over $V^{\otimes d}$, where we utilise the Einstein summation convention and $\lambda_{i_1, ..., i_d} \in K$ [1]. Let us consider the natural action of $GL(V)$ on $V^{\otimes d}$ and let $Orb_{GL(V)}(V^{\otimes d})$ be the set of orbits. It is well known that group orbits are disjoint, so the indicator function $I(\Lambda \in O)$ is only 1 for exactly one orbit $O \in Orb_{GL(V)}(V^{\otimes d})$.

The headline question is: is it possible to construct this indicator function?

I'm interested in the special cases $V = \mathbb{C}^n$, $K = \mathbb{C}$ and $V = \mathbb{R}^n$, $K = \mathbb{R}$.

I believe the answer requires a central component: a classification of the orbits of $GL(V)$ acting on $V^{\otimes d}$. I've been reading about representation theory in this area and I've come across irreducible tensor representations, Schur-Weyl duality etc. However, I'm not quite sure how it all connects to this problem.

[1] Apologies for the index notation: I'm a theoretical physicist by training.

Comment: No, this is an extremely hard problem. There is a huge literature, see for example geometric complexity theory writings of Landsberg and others.

Comment: @ZachTeitler thanks for the comment. I'll be sure to look into geometric complexity theory. Do you have any specific references? I have seen Landsberg has written a few introductions.